# Push an upstream new branch into origin

Tags: git

I forked a project a few weeks ago. The main repository is on a private server.

```
$ # on gitserver.com
$ git clone --bare main.com:myproject
```

Now I've added the upstream repo and fetched new data.

```
$ # on desktop.com
$ git clone gitserver.com:myproject
$ git remote add upstream main.com:myproject
$ git fetch upstream
```

When I try to push the upstream branches to my own remote repo, I get an error for branches that exist on upstream but not in origin.

```
$ git push origin refs/remotes/upstream/BRANCH_A:BRANCH_A
Everything up-to-date
$ git push origin refs/remotes/upstream/BRANCH_B:BRANCH_B
error: unable to push to unqualified destination: BRANCH_B
The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.
error: failed to push some refs to '...'
```

How can I create this remote branch on origin and push to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$ git push origin refs/remotes/upstream/BRANCH_A:refs/heads/BRANCH_A
```

if that doesn't work, try:

```
$ git checkout BRANCH_A; git push origin BRANCH_A
```

Comment: Thanks, the first line did it.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used to copy all branches from upstream to origin (bash):

```
 for i in .git/refs/remotes/upstream/*; 
 do 
   z=${i#.git/refs/remotes/upstream/}; 
   git push origin refs/remotes/upstream/$z:refs/heads/$z;  
 done
```

Copying all tags was easier as "git fetch upstream" will give me all tags locally:

```
git push --tags origin
```

Added this as it was also part of what I wanted to do.